# How to get category and subcategory of custom post type as nested array in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a small problem when get data from wordpress database. I want to get a nested array of category like:

```
array(
   "id" => "1",
   "name" => "categoryName",
   "children" => array(
        [0] => array(
            "id" => "2",
            "name" => "Name1",
            "children" => ""
        )
        [1] => array(
            "id" => "3",
            "name" => "Name2",
            "children" => ""
        )
   )
)
```

I have queried and get a table below:

```
|id   | name          | parent |
|_____|_______________|________|
|1    |categoryName   | 0      |
|_____|_______________|________|
|2    |Name1          |1       |
|_____|_______________|________|
|3    |Name2          |1       |
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please add the queries/code you have tried previously.

Comment: SELECT wp_terms.term_id AS id, name, parent FROM wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy WHERE wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id and taxonomy = 'album-category'